# select data conditionally in a json file

Tags: jquery, html, json

Is there a way to select data conditionally in a json file

```
[
   {"id":1,"price":10},
   {"id":1,"price":20},
   {"id":1,"price":30},
   {"id":2,"price":50},
   {"id":2,"price":60},
]
```

on clicking submit button on html page, if value of id=1 then only prices with id=1 should be visible  and same for id=2.

I have to do it using jquery.

Comment: You'd need to loop over this object and pull out the ones you want.  Or you could store it in a different format from the start (something like `{1: [10, 20, 30], 2: [50,60]}` or similar).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** to filter data.

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "price": 10
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "price": 20
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "price": 30
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "price": 50
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "price": 60
}, ];



$('#click').click(function() {
  var id = $('#id').val();
  console.log(data.filter(function(v) {
    return v.id == id;
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<button id="click">click</button>
```

To get array of price values you can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "price": 10
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "price": 20
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "price": 30
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "price": 50
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "price": 60
}, ];



$('#click').click(function() {
  var id = $('#id').val();
  $('#val').html(data.filter(function(v) {
    return v.id == id;
  }).map(function(v) {
    return v.price;
  }).join());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<div id="val"></div>

<button id="click">click</button>
```